# Uninstall without source mst

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm creating a windows install package with Transform to make it multi-instance. My mst file updates ProductCode and GUIDs of some registry entries components. This is per-machine installation. Now I cannot uninstall my product, if:

1. My mst file is removed from its original location
2. TransformsSecure policy is set to 1

The installer tries finding the mst file at the original location, cannot do that and fails uninstall.
What can I do to let my product to uninstall under those 2 conditions?

Some extra info.
I see that my msi and mst files are cached in "c:\Windows\Installer" folder. 
But somehow installer is not trying to take the mst from the cache.
Also everything is working well, if TransformsSecure policy is NOT set. In this case my mst file is automatically cached in "c:\Windows\Installer{358e77a7-464b-4588-b538-a79fceb0ffa8}" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post an entire verbose uninstall log somewhere, and it's not clear to me (sorry) if you cannot uninstall because of your 1 AND 2 or because of either 1 OR 2. So there's a certain amount of guesswork as it to your exact situation.

However, if the mst has been deleted from the installer cache then Windows will try to locate it at the original install source, just as it would if the cached MSI file was missing. However secure transforms disallow going to the original install source (because they can be retrieved only from the secure cached location, and not from the DVD, for example) so the uninstall will fail if the cached one is missing. So that's normal - secure transforms require access to the mst in the secure location and nowhere else. And yes, if transforms are not secure it can use the install source.

Sometimes the system account loses access to the installer cache location, and that would have the same result. It can't find the mst in the secure location, but transforms are secure so it can't use the original install source, so the operation fails.

So the details in the log may help. Does it get (say) system error 5 trying to get the mst? Or does it say something else about why it can't use it? And is there an an attempt to resolve the source that it doesn't do because transforms are secure?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post the log right now, my working computer is not available this weekend. But here are more details about what I'm doing.

I need to let my product to uninstall even if my msi and mst are not available at their source location.
I need to support TransformsSecure mode, cause it's 1 by default since Server 2008. Also some customers forces that.
I have a problem with uninstalling if both conditions are True. If one of them is False, it's ok.

Comment: I'm installing using the following command: msiexec -i "d:\Temp\MyProduct.msi" TRANSFORMS="d:\Temp\MyProduct.mst" MSINEWINSTANCE=1
It's important to use full path to mst, otherwise uninstall tries to find even d:\Temp\MyProduct.msi.

Comment: I'm checking MyProduct registry entry in the list of installed products, and see what names were generated to cache MyProduct.msi and MyProduct.mst in c:\WIndows\Installer". And these cached files are really in that folder and fully match the original files. Transforms registry key specifies only one item: d:\Temp\MyProduct.mst with value "<some-hex>.mst.
When I check the uninstall log, I see that the cached msi was used, but the cached mst is never mentioned.

Comment: @PhilDW: "Sometimes the system account loses access to the installer cache location ..." -> Are there reasons for this that can be taken into account in the design?

Comment: @Nickolay Penkrat: If you can still remember, have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

After so many years, the Windows Installer still seems to have the same problem. Thanks Microsoft for the constant ignoring. The advantage is that you do not have to adjust the fixes again and again ;)

To solve the problem, the transform files should be embedded. One of the following methods can be used for that:

[Embedding Customization Transforms as Substorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/embedding-customization-transforms-as-substorage)

[Manage Substorages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/manage-substorages)

[Msidb.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msidb-exe)

The property TRANSFORMS then looks like this:
TRANSFORMS=":MyProduct.mst"
(see [TRANSFORMS property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/transforms)).

Comment: I would have thought anyone doing product code changing transforms for multiple instance installation would be embedding their MSTs.  Good call out!  Honestly though, this isn't level 100 MSI so I'd think anyone even trying this should already be GURU level. Otherwise don't bother trying.